# wp-load without modifying index.php

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

We are using Magento with Wordpress and Composer to manage all dependencies.

To include Wordpress functionality in Magento we would normally modify the `index.php` file:

```
/**
 * Load Wordpress
 */
if (!strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin') && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'downloader')) {
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../wp/wp-load.php');
}
```

However, because we are using Composer the index.php is not checkedin to source control and any modifications to it will be lost.

Is there a better way to include `wp-load.php` in Magento without modifiying the core `index.php` file?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[You can configure your VHost to add the file before with `auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution, like a way to create a custom Magento extension? Is that possible?

Comment: I don'T see any way to add the wp-load early with a magento extension. When do you need it? You could listen on `resource_get_tablename` which is the first event thrown and require your file (and save the status to do it only once)

Comment: It is needed in the template code. The templates are using functions defined by Wordpress. I will have a look in to `resource_get_tablename`. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunetly observing the `resource_get_tablename` event doesn't work. The wp-load.php file needs to be included before the `/app/Mage.php` file otherwise the `Varien/Autoload.php` conflicts with what Wordpress needs to load